# Dynamic uiwebview height size based on content and uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiimageview

I have uiwebview with html code like this :

```
NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html  dir=\"rtl\"> \n"
                               "<head> \n"
                               "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                               "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
                               "</style> \n"
                               "</head> \n"
                               "<body>%@</body> \n"
                               "</html>", @"B BigFont", [NSNumber numberWithInt:18], self.Bodys];
 

self.htmlStrings = @[myDescriptionHTML];
for (NSString *html in self.htmlStrings) {
    UIWebView *webView = (UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    for (UIView *view in webView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;
            scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            
        }
    }
```

also in top of my view and webview i have Uiimageview :

```
    [bookpic setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.bookimageUrl]];
    __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = bookpic;
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.bookimageUrl]];
    [bookpic setImageWithURLRequest:request1
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]
                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                             UIImageView *strongImageView = weakImageView; // make local strong reference to protect against race conditions
                             if (!strongImageView) return;
                             
                             [UIView transitionWithView:strongImageView
                                               duration:0.3
                                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                             animations:^{
                                                 strongImageView.image = image;
                                             }
                                             completion:NULL];
                         }
                         failure:NULL];
```

as u can see my image position is static and my webview content is scrollable.

now i want to add uiimageview inside my webview and make both scrollable like

newsrepublic application.

this is how it handle webview with image :

[image]

another interesting thing is when u scroll news on Newsrepublic application the

imageview and webview scroll have different scroll speed and in the end the text

goes on top of the uiimageview plus the upper IOS label get disappear.

now how should i achieve this ? should i insert both my uiimageview and webview

inside uiscrollview ? or should i add uiimageview to uiwebview and let the

webview handle the scroll ?

Comment: get `dynamic height` of `webview` and `set its frame`. and then both add in `UIScrollView`. also `disable webview` scrolling.

Comment: is there any side effect for adding webview inside uiscroll view ?

Comment: Scrolling problem..

When user tries to scroll UIScrollview at time webview will get its scroll event.